# Using a CASE in a WHERE clause with BETWEEN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a where clause with a case statement that will look at @TimeType and then only return the rows that are between those time ranges. So basically I have 3 times (morning, afternoon, and evening). I'm getting a syntax error on using between. The start_time field is sql time data type. Here's what I have so far:

```
declare @TimeType int

select * from events
where
start_time = case 
when @TimeType = 0 then start_time between '00:00:00' and '11:59:00' 
when @TimeType = 1 then start_time between '12:00:00' and '16:59:00' 
when @TimeType = 2 then start_time between '17:00:00' and '23:59:00' 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use regular logic:

```
select e.* 
from events e
where (@TimeType = 0 and start_time between '00:00:00' and '11:59:00') or
      (@TimeType = 1 then start_time between '12:00:00' and '16:59:00') or 
      (@TimeType = 2 then start_time between '17:00:00' and '23:59:00');
```

In generally, using `case` expressions in `where` clauses is discouraged, because it impedes the optimizer . . . and it can be harder to follow.  Usually, the same logic can be expressed using basic boolean logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Boolean logic instead in `WHERE` clause :

```
WHERE (@TimeType = 0 AND start_time between '00:00:00' and '11:59:00') OR
      (@TimeType = 1 AND start_time between '12:00:00' and '16:59:00') OR
      (@TimeType = 2 AND start_time between '17:00:00' and '23:59:00')
```